# Laravel 8 - Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel

My Project Works Perfectly On Local Server But After I Have Upload It To Public Server. All Add Images Functions Give Me Same Error

Can't write image data to the path (upload/... I Am Using Laravel 8

here is my code when i add Service image

```
    if($request->hasFile('himage')) {

       $image=$request->file('himage');

       $imageName='service_header_'.$id.'.'.time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

       Image::make($image)->save('uploads/service/'.$imageName);



       OurService::where('service_id',$id)->update([

         'header_image'=>$imageName,

         'updated_at'=>Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),

       ]);

     }



  if($update){

   return redirect('admin/service/edit/'.$slug)->with('success', 'Service Update Successfully!');

   }else{

     return back()->with('error', 'Opps! Please try again');

 }
```

Comment: `chmod -R 777 storage uploads`

Comment: Permissions error probably. The local folder has permissions different than the folder on server.

Comment: I have changed the permission to  777, but it throws the same

Comment: why not try $path_front = Storage::putFileAs('uploads/service', $image, $imageName);